# Type mismatch junit5 @ExtendWith

Tags: junit4, junit5, jboss-arquillian, junit5-extension-model

so this is probably a really dumb question but I just started to migrate a project from junit 4 to 5 and saw that @RunWith() does not longer exists. It is replaced by @ExtendWith. So I tried to do it like this:

```
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

import de.msggillardon.services.journal.JournalService;
import de.msggillardon.system.UserContext;
import de.msggillardon.util.ITDeployment;

@ExtendWith(Arquillian.class)
.....
```

And I get the following exception: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class  to Class <? extends Extension>

I am a really bloody beginner and have no Idea how I can fix the problem.. So maybe someone could help me or tell me where I can find the necessary Information.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't use JUnit 4's `Runner` as your JUnit Jupiter (part of JUnit 5) extensions. That's a completely new API and not compatible.

> Although the JUnit Jupiter programming model and extension model will
> not support JUnit 4 features such as Rules and Runners natively, it is
> not expected that source code maintainers will need to update all of
> their existing tests, test extensions, and custom build test
> infrastructure to migrate to JUnit Jupiter. From the [official JUnit documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4)

So for each `@RunWith`, you need to use/include the JUnit Jupiter extension. In your particular case of Arquilian, I'm not quite sure if there is already an *official* extension for this.

The following links might help:

- https://developer.jboss.org/thread/274569
- https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-core/issues/137

Answer (score 0):

Arquillian now support junit 5.

Replace

```
@RunWith(Arquallian.class)
```

with

```
@ExtendWith(ArquillianExtension.class)
```

Also add the new dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit5</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit5-container</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0.Alpha10</version>
    </dependency>
```